# Javascript difference in behavior between chrome and firefox (event onmouseover)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, onmouseover

My intention is to make it so that the img will be visible only when I enter the mouse inside the boundaries of the input. The problem I have seen is that the code works differently in chrome (ver 39) than in firefox (ver 35).

In firefox and IE, it works as intended, but in chrome it only triggers the functions when I click inside or outside the boundaries. I tried using other events like onmouseenter, onmousemove or onmouseleave, but they seem to have the same results.

Is there some problem with my code?

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form><table><tr><td><input name="var1" id="var1"></td><td><img name="var1_img" id="var1_img" src="nostar.png" style="display:inline-block; position:relative; left:-20px" onclick="callClickEvent(this)"></td></tr></table></form>
<script>
var statusImg = 0;
function obtenerObj(idName) {
    var obj = null;
    if (document.getElementsByName && document.getElementsByName(idName)[0]) obj = document.getElementsByName(idName)[0];
    else if (document.getElementById && document.getElementById(idName)) obj = document.getElementById(idName);
    return obj;
}
function makeVisible(idName) {
    console.log("Visible "+idName);
    var obj = obtenerObj(idName+"_img");
    if (obj) obj.style.display = "inline-block";
}
function makeInvisible(idName) {
    console.log("Invisible "+idName);
    var obj = obtenerObj(idName+"_img");
    if (obj) obj.style.display = "none";
}
function callClickEvent(obj) {
    if (obj) {
        if (statusImg == 0) {
            obj.src = "star.png";
            statusImg = 1;
        } else {
            obj.src = "nostar.png";
            statusImg = 0;
        }
    }
}
var obj = obtenerObj("var1");
if (obj) {
    obj.onfocus = function() { makeVisible("var1"); };
    obj.onmouseover = function() { makeVisible("var1"); };
    obj.onmouseout = function() { makeInvisible("var1"); };
    obj.onblur = function() { makeInvisible("var1"); };
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger the event when you're hover the input, you need only onmouseover and onmouseout events.
I think that your problem is caused by the height of the td.
When you show the image the td become bigger and move down, to prevent this problem you could declare the height of the td with the same height of the image.

```
<td style="height:150px;"><input name="var1" id="var1"></td><td><img name="var1_img" id="var1_img" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" style="display:inline-block; position:relative; left:-20px" onclick="callClickEvent(this)"/></td>
```

Try [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/pKKaaLV40aI3sGXjw11l?p=preview) working example.

Comment: Sorry, but I still have the same behavior. It only goes visible/invisible when I click inside/outside the input.

Comment: Do you try my example?